# Unbiasing One-vs-all

Tags: classification

When you train a one-vs-all multi-class classification, the rule of thumb is that for each class (e.g. class A) mark it as class 0 and others as class 1. Then you split the data as you wish and train the classifier.

My question is, this creates a biased classifier: the number of samples of each class is not equal, the number of observations in *class A* is much smaller than *all others*. Should I take on measures to subsample all others or resample from *class A* to balance positive and negative observations for the classifier?

For example: take on a 5 class classification where for each class you have 5 observations. A one-vs-all means you mark for each class 5 positive examples and 20 negative examples.

Answer (score 0):

In such a case, you may have a biased estimator since data will be imbalanced as you mentioned. But this is ok as long as you are aware to the **different mis-classification errors (and their costs)** and their interpretations. All errors cost the same?

Yet, the question of whether to take care of the bias and how - depends on the interpretation of the final model.

If you want to *remove the bias during training*, this is not different than an imbalanced binary classifier. You can use proper *overfitting* and *balancing strategies* such as under/over-sampling, or setting **sample/class weight** to the estimator.

More important, one should also use the **appropriate performance metrics** to validate the model and investigate the misclassifications properly; balanced accuracy score, ROC AUC scores for each class ("one-vs-one"/"one-vs-all" and averaging by taking the support into account), plot AUCs for each class (TPR vs FPR, and precision-recall curves), and plot confusion matrix for each class. Although you're using "one-vs-all" strategy, validating the model as "one-vs-one" metrics will provide you additional validation on different biases.